# Fitting a function to a curve to then remove certain points

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, curve-fitting

I am trying to come up with a test that will only consider points that clearly follow the fitted curve. So, for my data below it would cut off any points below around x=0.13 as points below this don't follow the curve that well. Above x=0.13 you can see that it follows a clear curve. I am trying to minimise user input. Initially I was going to simply fit a power law curve to the data then calculate residuals and then come up with a maximum residual distance. But this means I'd have to give some value whereas I am trying to do it automatically without user input.

I have the following data below:

```
x = np.array([0.03751155, 0.05001541, 0.06251926, 0.07502311, 0.08752696,
        0.10003081, 0.11253466, 0.12503851, 0.13754236, 0.15004622,
       0.16255007, 0.17505392, 0.18755777, 0.20006162, 0.21256547,
       0.22506932, 0.23757318, 0.25007703, 0.26258088, 0.27508473,
       0.28758858, 0.30009243])
y = np.array([0.17091544, 0.2196002 , 0.24884891, 0.22784447, 0.365201,
       0.37375478, 0.39257039, 0.37231073, 0.41550739, 0.43636989,
       0.45111672, 0.46662792, 0.48854647, 0.49640163, 0.51887196,
       0.52827061, 0.54437941, 0.54929705, 0.56552202, 0.57508514,
      0.58477563, 0.59755615])
```

Which I have plotted using:

```
plt.scatter(x, y)

plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel("X Data")
plt.ylabel("Y Data")

plt.ylim(-0.05,0.65)
plt.xlim(-0.05,0.32)
```

[image]

**Edit**

The above data is simplified data. As requested, below is some realsitic data.

```
x = np.array([1.53989397, 2.04460628, 4.18043213, 2.97621482, 2.82642339,
       2.98335023, 2.98964836, 2.12218901, 1.42801972, 1.25930683,
       0.71644077, 0.48220866, 0.21165985, 0.24756609, 0.21123179,
       0.57344999, 0.49362762, 0.20282767, 0.50321186, 0.50347165,
       0.74259408, 0.48493783, 0.81785588, 0.54543666, 0.53218838])

y = array([1.53989397, 2.04460628, 4.18043213, 2.97621482, 2.82642339,
       2.98335023, 2.98964836, 2.12218901, 1.42801972, 1.25930683,
       0.71644077, 0.48220866, 0.21165985, 0.24756609, 0.21123179,
       0.57344999, 0.49362762, 0.20282767, 0.50321186, 0.50347165,
       0.74259408, 0.48493783, 0.81785588, 0.54543666, 0.53218838])
```

The image below displays the full context of what I am trying to do. I have implemented a weighted least squares fit. To do this I have added the (0,0) point to my data. For physical reasons my point (0,0) and the higher x value points should be weighted highly with the lower x values weighted very small which is shown by following function in my code:

```
def custom_weights(x):
    weights = np.ones_like(x)  # default weight for all points
    weights[(0 < x) & (x <= 0.2)] = 1  # medium error for 0 < x <= 0.2
    weights[x > 0.2] = 0.1  # low error for x > 0.15
    weights[np.isclose(x, 0, atol=1e-8)] = 0.001  # very low error for x = 0
    return weights
```

As you can see I need to choose a bound for where I define the "lower" x values which I can weight small. In this code I have done it by eye and chosen 0.2 as the bound. However, I am trying to come up with an way I can chose this bound without doing it by eye.

[image]

Comment: Why would you throw out data below 0.013? You seem to have perfectly good data that matches the general trend.

Comment: @jared this is just example data. My real data has significantly more noise at lower x values.

Comment: It's trivially easy to remove points below a threshold, but this is unlikely to serve your best interests. As jared says, there is likely still value in your true data below the threshold, but it is impossible to say for sure without seeing it. Graph and show your true data here. If it's too big to include inline, either decimate it to a lower resolution, or generate similar data with a constant random seed.

Comment: @Reinderien I have updated my question as per your suggestion.

Comment: are you trying to remove all data for (x, y) where yFit - yActual > thresholdValue ?

Comment: @D.L Not really as I don't necessarily know what yFit is - I am performing a weighted least squares fit of the data and I want to find the threshold x value where the different weightings should be applied.

Comment: @jim_athon,  if yFit is unknown, then the question has insufficient information to be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RANSAC regression partitions data into an inlier and outliers set, and might be useful in this case. I ran it on similar data to the sample you posted:

[image]

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RANSACRegressor, LinearRegression
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 0.03751155, 0.05001541, 0.06251926, 0.07502311, 0.08752696,
        0.10003081, 0.11253466, 0.12503851, 0.13754236, 0.15004622,
       0.16255007, 0.17505392, 0.18755777, 0.20006162, 0.21256547,
       0.22506932, 0.23757318, 0.25007703, 0.26258088, 0.27508473,
       0.28758858, 0.30009243, 0.32, 0.33, 0.35]).reshape(-1, 1)

y = np.array([0, 1.53989397, 2.04460628, 4.18043213, 2.97621482, 2.82642339,
       2.98335023, 2.98964836, 2.12218901, 1.42801972, 1.25930683,
       0.71644077, 0.48220866, 0.21165985, 0.24756609, 0.21123179,
       0.57344999, 0.49362762, 0.20282767, 0.50321186, 0.50347165,
       0.74259408, 0.48493783, 0.81785588, 0.54543666, 0.53218838])

# View data
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=1, linestyle='-', color='lightgray', zorder=0)
plt.scatter(x, y, color='lightgray', marker='o', s=100, label='original data')

#
#Fit RANSAC linear regression
#
ransac_lr = RANSACRegressor(
    estimator=LinearRegression(),
    min_samples=len(x) // 3, #Use at least 1/3 of the data per model
    max_trials=500,
    stop_score=0.95 #Stop if R2 is >= 95%
).fit(x, y)

#Get the trendline
trendline = ransac_lr.predict([[x.min()], [x.max()]])

#
# Visualise results
#
plt.scatter(x[~ransac_lr.inlier_mask_], y[~ransac_lr.inlier_mask_], marker='x', color='tab:red', label='outlier')
plt.scatter(x[ransac_lr.inlier_mask_], y[ransac_lr.inlier_mask_], marker='^', color='tab:green', label='inlier')
plt.plot([x.min(), x.max()], trendline, linewidth=8, color='tab:green', alpha=0.3, label='RANSAC regressor')
plt.gcf().legend()
plt.gca().set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y')

#Optional formatting
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(7, 3)
# remove right, top spines
[plt.gca().spines[spine].set_visible(False) for spine in ['right', 'top']]
# trim remaining spines
plt.gca().spines.left.set_bounds(y.min(), y.max())
plt.gca().spines.bottom.set_bounds(x.min(), x.max())
```